# PyQGIS map rendering export shows no map labels?

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, rendering

I'm trying to learn a little bit of Python in QGIS with the following tutorial: [QGIS Maprendering](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html).

Now the tutorial works, with minor adjustments.
In QGIS I have four layers, and one them is showing labels (country names), but when I export to PNG or PDF the labels of the layer won't show in the output file.

[image]

My code:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
import processing
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *

img = QImage(QSize(1200, 1000), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
color = QColor(250, 250, 250)
img.fill(color.rgb())
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)

p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
render = QgsMapRenderer()

layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
print layers

layers_ids = []
for layer in layers:
    print layer.id()
    layers_ids.append(layer.id())   

render.setLayerSet(layers_ids)
rect = QgsRectangle((iface.mapCanvas().extent().xMinimum()),(iface.mapCanvas().extent().yMinimum()),(iface.mapCanvas().extent().xMaximum()),(iface.mapCanvas().extent().yMaximum()))
rect.scale(1.1)
render.setExtent(rect)

render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
render.render(p)

p.end()

img.save("map2.png","png")
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: Not sure about that code snippet, another way to create an image from canvas extent is: iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage( 'C:/Temp/image.png')